# Handling autolayout special case

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, autolayout

I have established constraints to like buttons, timestamp button, etc. below bottom of textfield a certain distance. You can see the issue in the image; if the textfield doesn't have enough letters, they overlap, how do I fix this? Here's a link to image:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_btZBSsL3SQA1IulFTasMFBghF_2hJYzrFlbuQPkKrM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is setting the constraints with respect to the *bottom of textfield*. That bottom moves depending on the amount of text the field has and if that bottom position is above the bottom position of the icon to the left of the text field, you'll get the overlap you see. The solution, you might think, is to set the constraints with respect to the bottom of the icon but that won't work when the text field has a lot of text. You should try that just to understand the problem more clearly.

The actual solution is to set this particular constraint programmatically, as text is entered into the text field. You want to set that constraint with respect to the bottom of the view (icon or text field) that has the lowest bottom. That way, with little text, the constraint is set relative to the bottom of the icon but when there's enough text for the text field to vertically extend below the icon, the constraint is set relative to the text field instead.

Where would you set this constraint programmatically? Probably in the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate method of `UITextField`.

Alternatively - and perhaps a better solution - you could have a view containing the icon and the text field and set the constraint in question with respect to the bottom of the container view. That way you can set the constraint in IB rather than have to do it programmatically.

To clarify my answer, after the discussion in the comments below, here's a picture of what I mean by having container views and setting constraints between them to avoid the observed overlap.

[image]

Set appropriate constraints within each of the container views then set constraints between the container views and between them and the cell content view (I'm assuming, from your picture, that you have all of this in a table view so you have some template table view cell).

Comment: So how should I add a constraint between the buttons, which is what I want to do in the special case?

Comment: It's not clear to me what buttons you're referring to. All I see are icons and text fields and labels. Regardless, think of it this way: your icons, labels and textfields should form a self-contained group so put them inside of a view and set their constraints with respect to that view only, ignoring anything else. THEN, set constraints between those container views so that THEY don't overlap.

Comment: is there a way to programatically set a minimum cell height?

Comment: That's a completely separate question now. Yes, the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol has a method called -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: where you can compute the height you want to return.

Comment: Right but you cant mix that with autolayout. I can't not return a value for the ones I want to be automatically sized. I would want something like this in heightForRow: if special case(return 44) but ifNotSpecialCase(automatically size) and I don't know how to do that....do you know a way to do that?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why you're now shifting the question to setting a minimum cell height programmatically. If you follow the suggestion I gave of using container views and set the appropriate constraints correctly then you won't need to do anything programmatically to have the correct cell heights. The UITableView class will take care of it for you.